# How can I conditionally set a property for OpenCV dylib files with CMake?

Tags: opencv, cmake

I'm trying to have standard OpenCV installed at the same time as a custom version in a different directory under OS X. In doing so, I found that the OpenCV CMake causes linking to fail when the libraries are installed to a non-standard path (i.e. other than /usr/local). I was able to fix this by adding a line to `OpenCVModule.cmake`:

`set_target_properties(${the_module} PROPERTIES
    OUTPUT_NAME "${the_module}${OPENCV_DLLVERSION}"
    DEBUG_POSTFIX "${OPENCV_DEBUG_POSTFIX}"
    COMPILE_PDB_NAME "${the_module}${OPENCV_DLLVERSION}"
    COMPILE_PDB_NAME_DEBUG "${the_module}${OPENCV_DLLVERSION}${OPENCV_DEBUG_POSTFIX}"
    ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}
    COMPILE_PDB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}
    INSTALL_NAME_DIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib ## <--- Added this line
  )`

I'm trying to contribute this change back to the OpenCV project. But in the case where `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is set to "/usr/local" `INSTALL_NAME_DIR` should not be set. I've tried adding an `if` statement:

`set_target_properties(${the_module} PROPERTIES
    OUTPUT_NAME "${the_module}${OPENCV_DLLVERSION}"
    DEBUG_POSTFIX "${OPENCV_DEBUG_POSTFIX}"
    COMPILE_PDB_NAME "${the_module}${OPENCV_DLLVERSION}"
    COMPILE_PDB_NAME_DEBUG "${the_module}${OPENCV_DLLVERSION}${OPENCV_DEBUG_POSTFIX}"
    ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}
    COMPILE_PDB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}
    if(NOT ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX} STREQUAL "/usr/local") ## <--- this always evaluates to FALSE
        INSTALL_NAME_DIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib
    endif()
  )`

I haven't found any syntax that will cause the `if` statement to evaluate to `true`. Is there a way to get CMake to conditionally set `INSTALL_NAME_DIR` based on the contents of `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake commands cannot be nested: there is just no syntax for that. But you may execute any command under "if" branch:

```
if(NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX STREQUAL "/usr/local")
    set_target_properties(${the_module} PROPERTIES
        INSTALL_NAME_DIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib
    )
endif()
```

Note also, that preferred way for compare variable's value in "if" clause is to use variable's name, instead of dereferencing it. CMake will determine that variable with this name exists and automatically dereference it. This behaviour is described in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/if.html) for "if" command.